# Add reference of AngularJS.min.js in another javascript in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015

I am writing angularJS app in separate folder in Visual Studio. Location of my AngularJS-min.js file in different folder. my question how can I reference AngularJS-min.js file in my app javaScript file so that I can get auto suggestion while writing code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding it by `///` ....... see below to example..

[image]

Comment: it works, before I can just drag and drop it but it VS2017 it does not work.

Comment: @Crismogram Yes, the drag drop function for reference the JS file doesn't work on VS2017, I don't know why. But you can type it by your self, it's also work too. Just type `/// <reference path="` the VS2017 auto complete will help you :)